# Spark-Redis connection issue when using SSL port(6380)

Tags: apache-spark, redis

Followed this document(https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/configuration.md) to write records to Azure Redis Cache using Spark job deployed on the HDI cluster. Got it working for the non-SSL port(6379). However, when I changed it to SSL port(6380). I started seeing these errors. Wondering if anyone has faced it before? Appreciate the help and suggestions.
Below are the configurations used:

```
spark.redis.host = hostname of the Redis cluster
spark.redis.port = 6379
spark.redis.ssl = true
spark.redis.auth = auth-password
```

Here is the error that we're facing:

```
EXCEPTION: Message: Error writing messages to Redis Cache, StackTrace: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:59)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:234)
    at com.redislabs.provider.redis.ConnectionPool$.connect(ConnectionPool.scala:33)
    at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisEndpoint.connect(RedisConfig.scala:69)
    at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisConfig.clusterEnabled(RedisConfig.scala:193)
    at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisConfig.getNodes(RedisConfig.scala:317)
    at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisConfig.getHosts(RedisConfig.scala:233)
    at com.redislabs.provider.redis.RedisConfig.<init>(RedisConfig.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.RedisSourceRelation.<init>(RedisSourceRelation.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.redis.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:21)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
    at workflow.EvaluatedCostSender.publishEvaluatedCost(EvaluatedCostSender.scala:53)
    at workflow.Runner$.workflow$Runner$$publishEvaluatedCostData(Runner.scala:215)
    at workflow.Runner$$anonfun$main$5.apply$mcVI$sp(Runner.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at workflow.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:79)
    at workflow.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:678)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:43)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:155)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:220)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:318)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:236)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.auth(BinaryJedis.java:2259)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:836)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:434)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:127)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:199)
```

Comment: And this is more specific to the Spark-Redis connector. Any necessary settings that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was related to older Jedis and Spark-Redis versions. Moving to the latest ones helped resolve our issue.
Recommended versions:
jedis-3.6.2
spark-redis_2.11-2.6.0

Below spark-redis configuration are also needed:

```
"spark.redis.ssl": true,
"spark.redis.sslprotocols": "tls12",
"spark.redis.timeout": "120000"
```